# how to perform pagination in List inside a model in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, pagedlist

I have a model like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<Contacts> ContactList { get; set; }
}
public class Contacts
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Now in razor view, if we call the model like

```
@model MvcApp.Models.Customer
```

how to perform paging operation on **ContactList** that is inside the **Customer** model using PagedList or something.

Any help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want easy client side pagination then https://datatables.net/ would be your best option. Put Contacts into PartialView, make list displayed as table, apply datatables module, and it should look good.  If you want to use IPagedList then you would have to reload view every time when user clicks new page, because IPageList return one page at the time, and use of it on client side is not very good practice. However if you are ready to server calls:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public IPageList<Contacts> ContactList { get; set; }
}
```

Just load ContactList with page data on Server side every time when user clicks page.

Comment: Thanks Ssheverdin


if i call `@model MvcApp.Models.Customer` in my razor view, how to use this `public IPageList<Contacts> ContactList { get; set; }` with PageList ?

Thanks

Comment: There are many options on how you can make it work, and all of them depend on how you are finding and populating Customer model. Load the Customer model, then load contacts to list and make it paginated. After, send model to the view, and inside Customer View put ContactList into partial, Customer View will also hold pagination block, because Customer should know the page and its info. Try it yourself, and if you need more help, do it for the list, post(Controller,Views), and I will try to apply pagination.

Comment: Thanks Ssheverdin